# Order Statistics w/ Max

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d. r.v.s with CDF $F$, and let $M_n = \max(X_1,X_2, \ldots ,X_n)$. Find the joint distribution of $M_n$ and $M_{n+1}$, for each $n \geq 1$.

So, CDF of $M_{n+1}$ is given as, 
$$ \begin{align} 
P(M_{n+1} \leq x) &= P(X_1 ≤ x, X_2 ≤ x, \ldots, X_n ≤ x, X_{n+1} ≤ x ) \\
&= \underbrace{F(x) \times F(x) \times \ldots}_{(n+1) \text{ times}} \\
&= F(x)^{n+1}
\end{align}$$

We want to consider two cases: $P(M_n \leq a,M_{n+1} \leq b)$. However, after getting these facts, I am lost. Can someone help me in finding this joint distribution? Much thanks.

Comment: Maybe you consider $M_{n+1} = \max\{M_n, X_{n+1}\}$ can help you.

Comment: The $M_i$ are _order statistics._ Most mathematical statistics texts show how to find the distribution of an order statistic and then the joint distribution of any two of them. One reference is Bain & Englehardt: _Intro. to Prob. and Math. Stat,_ Sect 4.5. The relevant [_Wikipedia article_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) may also be helpful. (You need to consider the number of possible arrangements of observations smaller than a particular order statistic.)

Comment: Solution at:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312999/order-statistics-w-maximum

Comment: @BruceET The $M_i$ are not strictly order statistics. This is because there is a probability that $M_{n+1} = M_{n}$. By contrast, for order statistics, it is always the case that in a sample of size $n+1$, that the $n$th order statistic $X_{(n)} < X_{(n+1)}$

Comment: @wolfies: Right, I assumed a continuous distribution.

Comment: @BruceET I am also assuming a continuous distribution. $M_n$ is the maximum in a sample of size $n$:  if you add one extra value to the sample (which I assume is the OP's intention), and now have a sample of size $n+1$, the sample maximum $M_{n+1}$ may still be equal to $M_n$, if $X_{n+1}$ is not larger than all of the previous values. The $M_i$ are not order statistics, and they do not obey the ordered property that $M_n < M_{n+1}$